# What happens to stakers' rewards when initial supply of coins are ended?

Tags: bsc, proof-of-stake, polygon, staking

I was just reading about staking. Came to know that stakers stake their coins in the blockchain, validate the blocks and earn rewards. These rewards are from the initial supply of coins that is being staked. The coins are minted and sent to the verifier's address.

Now the confusion I have is that, what will happen to stekers, their staked amounts and the rewards when the initial supply of the coins will end?

For example a coin has 1000 supply and it all has been issued. Now from where the rewards will be given to the staker???

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing several different aspects here.

"Staker" is one that deposits currency/tokens, that's all. Each staking farm has different requirements and preks.

For instance, SOL owners can stake their currency to a validator, giving them more power to vote for blocks. The validator in return gives them part of the mining profits it generates, in a manner proportional to the Staker staked amount, rewards can be distributed from the SOL reward the miner receives.

Other farms have nothing to do with block validation, but just mint reward tokens as a reward to stakers.

Comment: my question is:
For the rewards, once total supply of SOL has been completely minted, then what will happen to the staking farm?
And another point was that, If I want to develop a staking project/Contract how can I do this... I will create an ERC20 token and that will be used for staking. People will have the rewards after investing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think the platform would buy back its tokens from the exchanges, or users to redistribute the rewards among the stakers.